# CTRL key check for right ALT in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, keyboard-events

I have simple code like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
var ctrl = false;
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    ctrl = true;
  }
  pre.innerHTML += 'keydown: ' + JSON.stringify({
    location: e.location,
    ctrlKey: ctrl,
    altKey: e.altKey,
    which: e.which
  }) + '\n';
});
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17) {
    ctrl = false;
  }
  pre.innerHTML += 'keyup: ' + JSON.stringify({
    location: e.location,
    ctrlKey: ctrl,
    altKey: e.altKey,
    which: e.which
  }) + '\n';
});
```

```html
<input>
<pre>
</pre>
```

And in google chrome the same as in Firefox and IE10 when you press right alt the `e.ctrlKey` is set to true, I've try to fix it by adding global variable ctrl and set it to true on keydown and set to false on keyup but that didn't fix it because when you press right alt keydown for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is fired and the same for keyup.

It this a bug or is it in a spec somewhere?

Is there a way to know if left alt was pressed without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right <kbd>Alt</kbd>, typically <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, is indeed equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. I don't know why, but it is.

So it's normal to get both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key and <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key from it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've just tested this on another laptop that don't have Alt Gr and just Alt on the keyboard and it send one keydown/keyup for right alt.